# Uncaught ArgumentCountError. Breaking down the meaning

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I'm hoping to get some help understanding of this fatal error.

**From looking at other post here's what I think I understand, please correct me if I'm wrong. The function get_excerpt() is currently passing 0 things (arguments)  and it's expecting to pass at least 1? I need to figure out how to tell the get_excerpt() to find at least 1 argument to pass?**

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function get_excerpt(), 0 passed in /nas/content/live/all4edstg/wp-content/themes/all4ed/page-press-room.php on line 74 and at least 1 expected in /nas/content/live/all4edstg/wp-content/themes/all4ed/functions.php:2420

Stack trace: #0 /nas/content/live/all4edstg/wp-content/themes/all4ed/page-press-room.php(74): get_excerpt() #1 /nas/content/live/all4edstg/wp-includes/template-loader.php(75): include('/nas/content/li...') #2 /nas/content/live/all4edstg/wp-blog-header.php(16): require_once('/nas/content/li...') #3 /nas/content/live/all4edstg/index.php(17): require('/nas/content/li...') #4 {main} thrown in /nas/content/live/all4edstg/wp-content/themes/all4ed/functions.php on line 2420

**Function.php line: 2420**

```
function get_excerpt ( $post, $limit = 200, $more = '...' ) {
$post = get_post($post);

if ( ! strlen($post->post_excerpt)) {
    return false;

}

if ($limit == -1) return $post->post_excerpt;

// Use the excerpt
$excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;
$excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $excerpt);

// Strip tags
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);

return trim_text($excerpt, $limit, $more);
}
```

**page-press-room.php line: 74**

```
    $leftcol .= '<p>'.get_excerpt().'</p>';
```

Comment: `$post` is required in the function call, since it does not have a default value.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but does the function already have post in it or is there another place I'm supposed to place it function ***get_excerpt ( $post ... ) ***

Comment: You must alway pass a `$post` variable into the function, e.g., `get_excerpt($post)`. The second two parameters (`$limit` and `$more`) are optional as they have default values defined in the function declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PHP's Default Function Arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

You'll notice the function is defined as such:

```
function get_excerpt( $post, $limit = 200, $more = '...' ){
```

This means that `$post` is required, because it doesn't have a default value, but `$limit` and `$more` can be omitted because they *do* have default values (200 characters, and faux-ellipses, respectively).

This means you have two options:

1) Rewrite the function to handle a default `$post` value

2) Pass a post into your function call `$leftcol .= '<p>'.get_excerpt( 1234 ).'</p>';`

The easiest way would be #2, and just pass the global post ID to the function, depending on the rest of your code it would look something like any of these:

```
 $leftcol .= '<p>'.get_excerpt( get_the_ID() ).'</p>';
 $leftcol .= '<p>'.get_excerpt( $post->ID ).'</p>';
 $leftcol .= '<p>'.get_excerpt( $post_id ).'</p>';
```

If these theme is one that won't be updated, you can update the function itself to handle a  global default, like many WordPress `get` functions do. Take a look at the documentation's source code for [`get_post_custom()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_custom/). It defaults to the `$post` to 0, so if an overriding value isn't set (like in option 2 above), it will default to the global post id via [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_ID/). That would look something like this:

```
function get_excerpt( $post = null, $limit = 200, $more = '...' ){
   if( $post == null ) $post = get_the_ID();

    $post = get_post( $post );

    if( ! strlen($post->post_excerpt) ){
        return false;
    }

    if( $limit == -1 )
        return $post->post_excerpt;

    // Use the excerpt
    $excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;
    $excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $excerpt);

    // Strip tags
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);

    return trim_text($excerpt, $limit, $more);
}
```

Comment: Wow this is so clear, thank you. I'm going to test this out now! :D Yes, I'm working form a very old theme that I cannot update. I'm in the process of reworking the whole site but I've run into problems with the theme since we had to move to PHP 7.2.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you @Xhynk